# What is this the name of this property of groups?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, examples-counterexamples

Let $G$ be a group such that for every $g,h\in G$, $[g,h^{-1}gh]=1$; that is, every element commutes with all its conjugates.

My questions:

1. Is there any name for such a property?
2. What are some examples of groups (where $G$ is non-Abelian) that satisfy this property?

**Edit:** I think that the [discrete Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Discrete_Heisenberg_group) $H_3(\mathbb{Z})=\langle x,y\mid [x,[x,y]]=[y,[x,y]]=1\rangle$ might be such an example but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Apparently, this means that every element of $G$ is a member of some abelian normal subgroup ([see this math.SE thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1400337/264)).

Comment: @ZevChonoles thanks! Are there any standarded terminology for this property? What are some examples?

Comment: The quaternion group $Q_8$.

Comment: If the group is finite then it will be nilpotent, so it suffices to understand $p$-groups with this property.

Comment: How does this property relate to solvable groups, if at all?

Answer (score 2):

These are the ***$2$-Engel groups***. Note that
$$
\mathbf{1 =\ } [g, h^{-1} g h] = [g, g [g, h]] = [g, [g, h]] [g,g]^{[g, h]}
= \mathbf{[g, [g, h]]}.
$$
So these are the group where for all $g, h \in G$ we have
$$
[[h,g]], g] = 1.
$$

Levi proved in

> F. W. Levi, Groups in which the commutator operations satisfy certain algebraic
>   conditions, J. Indian Math. Soc. 6 (1942) 87-97

that in a $2$-Engel group we have $[[a, b], c]^3 = 1$ for all $a, b, c$. So a $2$-Engel group is nilpotent of class at most $2$, unless it has $3$-torsion. And in this case one can show that it has class at most $3$.

See also [groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/2-Engel_group).

**Examples**

- Nilpotent groups of class $2$, of course.
- Slightly less trivially, the free group of exponent $3$ in $3$ generators is $2$-Engel, and has class $3$. Note that exponent $3$ implies $2$-Engel.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Do you happen to know another property that says that for all $g\in G$ and $h$ being a conjugate of $g$, $h^{-2}gh^2=g$?

Comment: Is it called a $3-$Engel group?

Comment: @Zuriel, not offhand. If I have something, I will be back to you.